# how to handle null date in c# for mysql without convert them to null

Tags: c#, mysql

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

i have this date in mysql as default date in undefined case

how i can get them in c# and re insert them without changes in MysqlDatabase.

if i get them in c#. i got error that `Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime`

how i can get this in c# and insert them without any changes in date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Nullable` types and the `as` operator to represent your datetime values in C#. This is the easiest mechanism to deal with database types which map to value types and potentially have no value. For example:

```
object valueFromMySQL = GetValueFromMySQL(); // or whatever
DateTime? datetimeValue = valueFromMySQL as DateTime?;
```

If the value is valid, it will be interpreted as `DateTime`, otherwise it will be interpreted as null.

You should also be able to send values of the type `DateTime?` back to MySQL without issue.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.MinValue` (the minimum value `DateTime` supports) is 1-1-0001 0:00:00. Is it an option to set your MySQL default that date date/time instead of 0-0-0000 0:00:00? The problem here is that the date/time you've set as your default is not a valid date/time (there is no month with the number zero), so `DateTime` will never accept this date.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the try parse in this case.

```
DateTime ReturnedDateValue;

DateTime DateFromSqlDB = EntityClass.DateCreated;

if (DateTime.TryParse(DateFromSqlDB, ReturnedDateValue))
{
    /// Do the insert stuff here
}
```